# Google Analytics iOS. How to use -send:params: ?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

API version is GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta4.
The problem I'm dealing with is next:
f.e. I have several screens with one of them called PagesScreen.
PagesScreen have several pages.
In addition to screen tracking, I wish to track pages visited by user.

If I use custom dimension, f.e. pageName in conjunction with 
[tracker sendView:@"Page View"], obviously, each time page changes, page visits being added to  screen visits with @"Page View" screen name. I don't want to page views statistics being mixed with screen views. Therefore I don't have to call sendView: API. sendEvent: API is also not suitable for my case.

The remaining method is:
- (BOOL)send:(NSString *)trackType params:(NSDictionary *)parameters;
But neither it's description tells me about usage, nor mentions I've found in iOS integration guide.
What is trackType and what is parameters structure? Does anybody knows how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find the allowed trackTypes and required parameters on the following page:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

For instance, to send an event via send:parameters, the trackType should be @"event" and should have the following keys/values:

```
&ec=video       // Event Category. Required.
&ea=play        // Event Action. Required.
&el=holiday     // Event label.
&ev=300         // Event value.
```

Hope this helps!